# "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005. I get this error:

> *The multi-part identifier "ms.MOP_desc" could not be bound.*

I tested each of the two select queries and they worked fine individually, but I got the error when I union those queries. Can I anyone tell me what went wrong with this query? Thank you.

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount, ms.MOP_desc
FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(hd.delivery_value) AS Amount, ms.MOP_desc
    FROM TRANSACTION_HEADER AS th 
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_DETAIL AS td 
            ON th.transaction_number = td.transaction_number 
        LEFT JOIN hose_delivery hd 
            ON td.delivery_id = hd.delivery_id 
        LEFT JOIN product pr 
            ON pr.product_id = td.product_id
        INNER JOIN MOP_Setting AS ms 
            ON hd.MOP_ID = ms.MOP_ID  
    WHERE hd.delivery_value > 0 
        AND (th.USER_PERIOD_ID IN (13))
        AND (hd.MOP_ID  IN (1))
        AND hd.Cleared_By != '0'
    GROUP BY ms.MOP_desc

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  SUM(td.quantity * td.price_sold) AS Amount, ms.MOP_desc 
    FROM TRANSACTION_HEADER AS th 
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_DETAIL AS td 
            ON th.transaction_number = td.transaction_number 
        INNER JOIN MOP_Setting AS ms 
            ON th.MOP_ID = ms.MOP_ID  
    WHERE (th.USER_PERIOD_ID IN (13))
        AND (th.MOP_ID  IN (1))
    GROUP BY ms.MOP_desc
)t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the result from the `UNION`ed query is a rowset that you've given the alias `t` to - the `ms` alias is no longer applicable:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount, t.MOP_desc
FROM 
(
...
)t
```

If this really is a second `SUM` step here, you'll need a outer `GROUP BY` clause also.

Answer (score 1):

When you select from a subselect instead of a table, the column names from the subselect are not exposed to the outer select

Use

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount, mop
FROM 
(
  SELECT SUM(hd.delivery_value) AS Amount, ms.MOP_desc as mop
  FROM TRANSACTION_HEADER AS th 
      INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_DETAIL AS td 
...
```

Comment: That is the reason why you do not get this error for Amount. You have already assigned a column name to that column in your query.

Comment: "the column names from the subselect are not exposed to the outer select" is blatantly *not* true. You have to give a name to any otherwise *unnamed* columns (such as the `SUM`), but column names are preserved

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thank you for the hint. I guess I took the wrong conclusions from testing a similar query locally.

Comment: @ixora - it worked because you removed the `ms.` prefix. You could have done the same in your original query and not renamed the column at all. This explanation is pure bunkum.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Given that was the case, then I would not need to give ms.MOP_desc a new name, namely mop as described by  LuigiEdlCarno above. Therefore where does the problem with my query really lies?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Please ignore my latest comment. I posted that before seeing your latest comment.